# Eps file is so large

Tags: eps

I am writing  a paper in latex and need to insert .eps figure. I drew the figure in powerpoint, then saved the .ppt as .pdf and opened it in photoshop. I noticed when I opened it, the size was like 127cm*48cm and the dpi is 300, the file was 274MB, I changed the dpi to 600 and it became 900+MB... so large... I then croped the picture from it and save it as eps. I did changed it the size of the picture to about 10cm*3 (I kept the width/length ratio unchanged) but still the file is about 200MB. too large to me to submit it. Where did I a do it wrong? I noticed that my other eps directly exported from Matlab are just 30kB. Thank you.

Comment: This question is definitely an off-topic. It has nothing to do with LaTeX. Also, this kind of workflow is awful. I have no idea why you need to use PowerPoint with PDF as an intermediate.

Comment: @m0nhawk I consider preparing an external image for input in LaTeX in best quality as on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid saving possible vector data as bitmap in PhotoShop. White margins can be cropped at PDF level via `pdfcrop`. The PDF can be converted to EPS by `pdftops -eps`.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I will convert pdf to eps directly https://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/pictips.html